# Two different ClickOnce applications cannot be installed on same computer

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce

I have a .NET 4 WPF ClickOnce deployment that installs and works fine. However we also have a different .NET 3.5 WPF application which is signed with different keys that installs from the same server and a different URL location that fails install if the first application is already installed. Same goes if the .NET 3.5 app is installed first and I try to install the .NET 4 app second, it fails. This has been replicated on multiple machines and the StackTrace is noted below.

```
Application cannot start...

+ Exception occurred during store operation.
+ Value does not fall within the expected range.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [12/17/2012 8:06:51 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (ComponentStore)
- Exception occurred during store operation.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.SubmitStoreTransaction(StoreTransactionContext storeTxn, SubscriptionState subState)
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
--- Inner Exception ---
System.ArgumentException
- Value does not fall within the expected range.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.Transact(IntPtr cOperation, StoreTransactionOperation[] rgOperations, UInt32[] rgDispositions, Int32[] rgResults)
```

Any ideas why these two applications would be conflicting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was with two assemblies I was using...that work fine when the application is installed alone but somehow conflict with the 3.5 application (which uses older version of same assemblies).

The assemblies that caused the problem are:

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common-4.1.0.0.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling-4.1.0.0.dll

I removed these and replaced with newer 5.0.* version and could publish and install both applications on the same machine.

These are the new dll names:

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll